# Object property spreading and Object.assign

Tags: javascript

I noticed a weird behavior of the spreading operator. I want to remap each element of a plain array in a pair key-value (an Object). If the element in the array is `a`, I want to map it as `{a:"a"}`.

Spreading the result of `map` results in a weird object with numeric indexes in the first example, while `Object.assign()` behaves as expected.

```
var a = ["a","b","c"]

{...a.map( el => ( {[el]: el}))}
>> {0: {a: "a"}, 1: {b: "b"}, 2: {c: "c"}}

Object.assign({},...a.map( el => ( {[el]: el})))
>> {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}
```

What's the problem here? (tried in Chrome 79)

Comment: They keys of an array are the indexes. This is what happens if you spread it as an object with `{...`

Comment: I spread the array exactly the same way with Object.assign..

Comment: Try `{ ...a }` and you should see what's happening a little easier.

Comment: Also, you aren't doing the same thing. The equivalent with `Object.assign` is `Object.assign({}, { ...a.map( el => ( {[el]: el}))})`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I get both your point, why Object.assign "ignores" numeric indexes? There is a way to fix it?

Comment: Spreading in `Object.assign` is spreading function arguments. That is a completely different semantic, than spreading in an object literal.

Comment: @alfredopacino your second example is equivalent to: `Object.assign({}, {"a": "a"}, {"b": "b"}, {"c": "c"})` -- you are spreading an array into the arguments of the function.

Comment: Spreading into function arguments means taking the *values* of an iterable as arguments. Spreading into an object literal, means taking the key/value pairs from an *object* (in your case an array -- so, with index keys) and use them as key/value pairs in the constructed object. Completely different semantic.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, it's more clear now. is there a way to "fix" it?

Comment: What do mean fix? What's your desired output from which method?

Comment: `a.reduce((obj,k) => (obj[k] = k, obj), {})`

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments in the question mention, in the first case, you are destructuring an array inside brackets, which is interpreted as creating an object with the index

```js
a.map(el => ({[el]: el})); // [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"}]
{...a.map(el => ({[el]: el}))}; // {"0": { a: "a" }, "1": {b: "b"}, "2": {c: "c"}}
```

In the second case, you are merging the properties of each element in the array with the empty object passed to `Object.assign`

```js
Object.assign({}, ...[{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"}]) // is equivalent to
Object.assign({}, {a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"});
```

See [MDN Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = { a: 'a' };
const b = { b: 'b' };

console.log(
    "These are the same:",
    { ...[a, b] },
    { 0: a, 1: b },
);

console.log(
    "These are the same:",
    Object.assign(...[a, b]),
    Object.assign(a, b),
    { ...a, ...b },
);

console.log(
    "These are NOT the same:",
    { ...[a, b] },
    { ...a, ...b },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `{...obj}` is just a copy of the object with "own" and "enumerable" properties.  Because `a.map( el => ( {[el]: el}))` is an array, and that's why the final result is also array-like.

As stated in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59742733/325418), your `Object.assign` statement is equivalent to

```
Object.assign({}, {a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"});
```

so that's why it succeeded.

You also can do:

(inside of NodeJS)

```
> a.reduce((acc, e) => { acc[e] = e; return acc; }, {})
{ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }

> a.reduce((acc, e) => (acc[e] = e, acc), {})
{ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }
```

Comment: while `reduce` seems to be a solution, I think it is less clear than `Object.assign`..

Comment: I tend to like to use `reduce` when it is functional as opposed to procedural. Spreading in Object.assign can stackoverflow if the the number of arguments is more than 65536 or something like that... not usually but depends on where and how it is used